# How do i Listen or Observe an Firebase cloud firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on simple application which has 2 activities. first one shows ListView(gets data from cloud Firestore) and 1 button, last one has functions to change the data of my Firestore or add new data.

My problem is my ListView items are not changing until i restart my application. I want it to notify an updates and show it to me when i presses back button from second activity.

So i want to add Listener for my cloud Firestore's database or i want to get last added or updated documents that didn't requested. 
Then i can change or add it to my ListView on onStart() function.

This is how i retrieve my data and mCollectionRef is Collection Reference

```
        mCollectionRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                    Book tempBook = new Book(documentSnapshot.getId(),documentSnapshot.getString("title"),documentSnapshot.getString("author"),documentSnapshot.getString("publisher"),documentSnapshot.getLong("copies"));
                    booksList.add(tempBook);
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.v("Error on book documents", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `notifydatasetchanged()`:

> `notifyDataSetChanged()`
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Yes I'm using it but ListView or it's adapter has no change at all. reason why is I fill my List with data only when activity created. and when i press back button from second activity my first activity doesn't call onCreate() again

Comment: When you press back button onStart() will be called, so you need to retrieve data inside onStart instead of onCreate, inside onCreate() you can set your views

Comment: Thank you! so if i retrieve my data inside onStart it will retrieve my whole collection from firebase again right?

Comment: Yes. OnStart is called when pressing back, and it is called after onCreate on activity launch

Comment: If the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful, thank you!

Comment: Okay but actually it didn't solve my problem completely because i don't wanna retrieve all my data(it's huge) every time i relaunch my activity

Comment: Then you can use persistent enabled to cache ur data

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities